# Split profile page to add site specific part

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I would like to be able to have different profiles on the different stack exchange sites.

But on the other side I want to be able to create a common profile for all network sites.

Therefore my request is to add a splitted profile. One part of this profile would be the current network profile. The second part would be specific for the site where this part is created. So I would have a common part of my profile for all sites and a specific part for each site independent.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I want a profile that is split into two parts. One network profile that will be displayed on every stackexchange site I participate and a profile part that is specific for the stachexchange site I set it for. E.g. I want to have a part like "Hello, I'm ..." on every site and a part with my GitHub repositories only on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can already add a "Hello, I'm ... " message to every site. Once you update your profile, you can choose to either "save changes for this community", or "save and copy changes to all SE communities" ... This way you can set a general message for all sites, and then customize it for 1 or 2 sites if you want.  In addition, you have the 'network profile' (there's a link on your profile page) which shows your contributions across all SE sites.